# Confidence Interval for the difference in two proportions

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

Could you please help me understand why the following reasoning is wrong:
let's say there are two random independent samples:
x1=56, n1=250, so that phat1=0.224, and
x2=60, n2=300, so that phat2=0.2.

Suppose I want a 95% confidence interval for the difference in population proportions. Using the standard technique, I would get phat1-phat2=0.024, se=0.0351, and the interval is (-0.045, 0.093).

However, if I constructed two separate 95% confidence intervals for p1 and p2, I would get (0.172, 0.276) for p1, and (0.155, 0.245) for p2, so that (p1-p2) has to be in (-0.073, 0.121).

What is the problem with the second approach? I understand the math part: the second approach adds up the standard errors, which is wrong. But why is the logic wrong? If p1 is in (x1, y1), and p2 is in (x2, y2), shouldn't the difference be in (x1-y2, y1-x2)?

Comment: The difference *might* be in that interval, but it has much more than a 95% chance to be there.  Thus, the logic is fine, but the conclusion that it creates a 95% CI is not justified.

Comment: Thank you! Is it because if p1 is outside (x1, y1) and p2 outside (x2, y2), p1-p2 can still fall into (x1-y2, y1-x2)?